# None in class method

Tags: python

I'm doing an exercise and I need the method analisar_lados to not return anything as it is returning None and that's not what I wanted. How do I fix this?

```
class Triang:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c

    def istriang(self):
        if self.a >= self.b+self.c:
            return False
        return True

    def analisar_angulos(self):
        if self.a**2 == self.b**2 + self.c**2:
            return 'TRIANGULO RETANGULO'
        elif self.a**2 > self.b**2 + self.c**2:
            return 'TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO'
        elif self.a**2 < self.b**2 + self.c**2:
            return 'TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO'

    def analisar_lados(self):
        if self.a == self.b == self.c:
            return 'TRIANGULO EQUILATERO'
        elif (self.a == self.b and self.a != self.c) or (self.a == self.c and self.a != self.b) or (self.b == self.c and self.b != self.a):
            return 'TRIANGULO ISOSCELES'
        else:
            pass


entrada = [float(item) for item in input().split()]  # INPUT: 6 8 10
entrada.sort(reverse=True)
A, B, C = entrada
triangulo = Triang(A, B, C)
if triangulo.istriang():
    print(triangulo.analisar_angulos())  # 'TRIANGULO RETANGULO'
    print(triangulo.analisar_lados())  # None
else:
    print('NAO FORMA TRIANGULO')
```

Comment: `None` is nothing. Are you talking about `analisar_angulos`?

Comment: He mistaken his comparison operator. In Math `a =b = c` is a legit statement. But in Coding, it quite different. ` a==b==c` equivalent to `a== (b==c)` or  `a == (True or False)` . This is not what he want. Use `a == b and b == c` instead

Comment: And a statement like `a**2 == b**2 + c**2` , I would refer to write it as `a**2 == (b**2 + c**2)` for clean code

Comment: try printing the return value of print to see what u get

Comment: @Silver -- You are completely wrong.  What you say is true in C, but in Python, `a == b == c` is a perfectly valid expression that returns True if the 3 values are equal.  Similarly, `5 < a < 15` also works as you would expect.

Comment: I suspect you want `return ''` instead of `pass`.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you show me the PEP which support your point? I do see it by testing myself but I do not remember read it in any PEP

Comment: No, because a PEP is used to outline a proposed change in Python.  The comparison syntax has always been there.  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

Comment: help me here please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72131204/project-structure-in-python-and-imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike languages like C, in Python, every function returns something.  If you have a bare `return` or execution reaches the end of the function without a `return` statement, then `None` is implicitly returned.  There is no way to not return anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `analisar_lados` as a procedure and not as a function. What is the difference between a procedure and a function? Function returns something whereas procedure dosen't.

Procedure

```
   def analisar_lados(self):
        if self.a == self.b == self.c:
            print('TRIANGULO EQUILATERO')
        elif (self.a == self.b and self.a != self.c) or (self.a == self.c and self.a != self.b) or (self.b == self.c and self.b != self.a):
            print('TRIANGULO ISOSCELES')
```

you may need to rewrite your code slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Although what Daniel Walker said is true, you can work around not printing `None` with something like this:

```
output = triangulo.analisar_lados()
print(output) if output else None
```

Additionally, assuming only one of the two will ever return a value, you could re-write the last couple lines like this:

```
if triangulo.istriang():
    angulos = triangulo.analisar_angulos()
    lados = triangulo.analisar_lados()
    print(angulos) if angulos else print(lados)
else:
    print('NAO FORMA TRIANGULO')
```

To take everything a step further... you could just re-write the functions entirely:

```
class Triang:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c

    def analisar(self):
        if self.a >= self.b+self.c:
            return 'NAO FORMA TRIANGULO'
        if self.a**2 == self.b**2 + self.c**2:
            return 'TRIANGULO RETANGULO'
        if self.a**2 > self.b**2 + self.c**2:
            return 'TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO'
        if self.a**2 < self.b**2 + self.c**2:
            return 'TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO'
        if self.a == self.b == self.c:
            return 'TRIANGULO EQUILATERO'
        if (self.a == self.b and self.a != self.c) or (self.a == self.c and self.a != self.b) or (self.b == self.c and self.b != self.a):
            return 'TRIANGULO ISOSCELES'


entrada = [float(item) for item in input().split()]  # INPUT: 6 8 10
entrada.sort(reverse=True)
A, B, C = entrada
triangulo = Triang(A, B, C)
print(triangulo.analisar())  # 'TRIANGULO RETANGULO'
```